# Raduis tags - pass variable as tag param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

I've installed [radiant variables extension](https://github.com/SwankInnovations/radiant-variables-extension), so now i can define var like

```
 <r:set_vars nav_pages="Tour: /tour | News: /news | Locations: /locations" />
```

And i had idea to use it in navigation snippet, something like

```
  <r:navigation urls="<r:puts value_for="vars[nav_pages]"/>">
    <r:normal><li><a href="<r:path />"><r:title /></a></li></r:normal> 
  </r:navigation>
```

certainly this will not work, at least because of quotes. Is there a way to implement this somehow? what i actually need is some common way to use a variable, accessible with tag, as a snippet argument. Or there should be some way to access variable without a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed not possible to nest radius tags like that. There is one way to get around that, being to use double tags. I have succesfully hacked other tags this way, making them accept params from another radius tag if they are 'double' tags (`<r:tag></r:tag>` i.o. `<r:tag/>`)
So with the hack in place you could do this:

```
<r:navigation>
  <r:normal><li><a href="<r:path />"><r:title /></a></li></r:normal> 
  <r:urls><r:puts value_for="vars[nav_pages]"/></r:urls>
</r:navigation>
```

That would require calling `tag.expand` somewhere like this;

```
urls = tag.attr['urls'] || tag.expand
```

Comment: By the way, r:snippet can yield passed variables by default;
<r:snippet name="title_block">Foo</r:snippet>

And in the title_block snippet, use <r:yield/> where you want 'Foo' to appear. This is achieved using the same strategy I explained above.

Comment: do you mean to call expand as `<r:navigation urls = tag.attr['urls'] || tag.expand>`? if i try like this, i'm getting `wrong end tag `navigation' found for start tag `' with stack []`. in case i do it without expand i have `undefined tag `urls'`
i use yielding with r:snippet, but it is useless in case i need to pass varaiables...

Comment: nope, you would have to create an extension that overrides r:navigation, have a look at radiant/app/models/standard_tags.rb to see your starting point. If you've never created a Radiant extension before, you should probably just abandon the idea... :)

Comment: well could be better, cold be worse. what would you reommend to get involved?

Comment: This must be your lucky day..;
https://github.com/jomz/radiant-navigation_tag_tweak-extension

Comment: As a final thought: I think that you are either trying to make radiant do things that it's not really made for (which is ok, maybe), or there is a much simpler way to do it..

Comment: deam, that works! i've already figured out i have to add it after `:normal, :here, :selected, :between`, but... hash[].call... my brain is cracked, i wouldn't guess. thx a lot!

i'm actually building some framework to enable fast creating of simple homepages. it is based on multi-site extension, and idea is to maximize code reuse, e.g. to define some layout for each tenant and specify available pages, and then just call snippet to draw navigation. and i see now, i'll have same issues with galleries... where am i exactly wrong?

Comment: For the navigation, give https://github.com/jomz/navigation_tags a try. It's a simpler tag that automatically builds navigation for all it's children. You can exclude pages by giving them a 'no-map' page part.

For galleries, I believe you can couple a gallery to any page using a dropdown 'base gallery' somewhere.